# How to delete all content inside of fhir store using Curl command

Tags: bash, curl, google-cloud-platform, google-healthcare-api

Im trying to implement a script which clean(delete all data, but not destroy the store)
here are some examples:

this deletes one single record

```
curl -X DELETE \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
     "https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT-ID/locations/LOCATION-ID/datasets/DATASET-ID/fhirStores/FHIR-STORE-ID/fhir/SupplyDelivery/SUPPLYDELLIVERY-ID"
```

this deletes all the data, BUT also destroy the store

```
curl -X DELETE \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
     "https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT-ID/locations/LOCATION-ID/datasets/DATASET-ID/fhirStores/FHIR-STORE-ID"
```

How to delete all the data, but not destroying the store??

I have tried placing `*` on front of store I want to clean like: `FHIR-STORE-ID/*` but it doesn't work

Comment: Looks like you need to use [`fhirStores.patch`](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.datasets.fhirStores/patch) to set updatable properties.

Comment: There are 3 delete APIs in the Cloud Healthcare API: delete a resource, delete all versions of a resource, and delete the FHIR store. Maybe I can help if you outline what your use case is for deleting all resources without deleting the store?

Comment: thanks Daz, I will look into this doc.

Comment: thanks Nik, oh I see.. it seems what i want to do is not supported by the api. Will read more about the api